# I see ads on this site. Are they real or do I have a problem?

Tags: support

I don't see ads in other StackExchange sites except for this one, where I find what seems Google Ads.

Are there ads of the site, or is something in my computer adding ads to the site?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are ads on [every SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329763/376358) since June.

Depending on your reputation, they might not be shown.

Of course, unless you set in your profile preferences to see them always.

Comment: The reputation limit reason makes sense because I have some reputation in most of the SE sites I usually read, except for Aviation. Probably, I've only noticed adds here because they aren't shown to me in other sites.